# Como salvar no mongodb um objeto json,que é a resposta de um post da API

Tags: json, node.js, api, mongodb, mongoose

Preciso salvar um determinado campo,de um objeto json,que vem da resposta de uma API que eu chamei.

Salvar alguns campos desse objeto json de resposta,em alguns campos da minha colletion/model no **MongoDB** usando também o pacote: **Mongoose**,**Node/Express**.

Eu imprimo do **data/response** que é o objeto de retorno completo,porém quero apenas o campo **number_token** que é o campo **que preciso salvar no banco de dados**.

Então na resposta eu seleciono apenas o **number_token** para ser retornado:

**return res.json(data.data.number_token);**

*Exemplo:*

```
.then(data => {
      //console.log("data", data);
      return res.json(data.data.number_token);
}
```

Ele me retorna o valor correto do **number_token**.A cada chamada terei um novo **number_token**.Agora preciso salvar cada resposta,o number_token resposta,no number_token da minha colletion/model no MongoDB.

```
"9a17a5712c46a28ca824183e46b2e8e68f40c4b3ff136ed9251eda43904bfb00f7891e7c979473172ff0756860a7796bf8ce386e46c80a0b3b69410c9739c4c3"
```

Agora preciso salvar essa variável no banco a cada nova requisição.
**number_token** banco mongodb,lib mongoose,express,node.

Segue a model:

```
  number_token: {         
    type: Number,
    //required: true
  },
```

Eu posso passar qualquer input do usuário com o **req.body** e salvar os campos passados no meu banco com a função do mongoose ***.save();***.

Porém eu ainda não entendi a lógica necessária para salvar esse retorno do **number_token** no meu banco.Já tenho a model conectada e o campo **number_token** na model.O problema está na lógica de como pegar esse retorno e salvar no banco.

Eu pensei em fazer assim:

```
.then(function(response) {
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.token));
      //res.json(response.data.token);

      const {number_token } =  res.body.token;
      
       const numberToken = new MyModel({
         number_token,
       });

       numberToken.save();


    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Porém ainda não entendi como pegar esse valor e salvar no banco.Eu pensei que o modo correto seria salvar o number_token em uma variável, e depois salvar no banco,junto com os dados passados no req.body,post da requisição,e salvar tudo de uma única vez no banco mongo.

Comment: Resolvido!era preciso salvar o valor recebido da resposta,em uma nova variável e depois salvar tudo no banco.Era um processo bem simples e eu acabei demorando um pouco para acertar o code.

 ```

.then(function(response) {
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.token));
      

      const token_card = response.data.token;
      console.log(token_card);
      const cardToken = new MyModel({
        
        token_card,
            
      });

      cardToken.save();


```

Comment: Você pode postar a resposta para a sua pergunta. Não existe restrição em relação a isso.

Comment: @Danizavtz,não consigo publicar respostas,estou com restrição. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido!

Era preciso salvar o valor recebido da resposta,em uma nova variável e depois salvar tudo no banco.Era um processo bem simples e eu acabei demorando um pouco para acertar o code.

```
 .then(function(response) {  

 const token_card = response.data.token;
 const cardToken = new MyModel({

 token_card, 

}); 

CardToken.save();
```